# VMware Console Keyboard Map Wrong

Tags: linux, vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm building a virtual disk image of an install from a script process (DD image, chroot to install). I then convert this image to a VMware vmdk image and boot it. I'm installing CentOS 6.4 as the guest operating system.

The guest boots and I'm able to SSH in. From SSH, this works perfectly.

If I try to use the VMware console to log in, many keys are mapped incorrectly. For example, pressing / (forward slash) generates a - (hyphen/dash). The keyboard map is incorrect on both Fusion and vSphere hosts.

What is the correct keyboard map to change to in order to fix the console?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the vmtools?

Comment: Yes, VMware tools install did not fix the problem.